# One or multiple models/tables for relation that can exist on multiple models

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, polymorphism

I have a model "Wine" and a model "Drink". Both Wine and Drink should have a type (type_id).

So the DB should look something like this:

### Wine

```
id, name, type_id, etc.
```

### Drink

```
id, name, type_id, etc.
```

---

My question is:

Should I

1. make a model "DrinkType" and a model "WineType" or
2. should I only use one, called "Type"?

### WineType

`id, name`

### DrinkType

`id, name`

### Type

`id, name, type`

---

DB Example for nr. 1:

### Wines

- id, name, wine_type_id
- 1, Test wine 1, 1
- 2, Test wine 2, 2

### Drinks

- id, name, drink_type_id
- 1, Test drink, 1

### WineTypes

- id, name
- 1, Red
- 2, White

### DrinkTypes

- id, name
- 1, Cocktails

---

DB Example for nr. 2:

### Wines

- id, name, type_id
- 1, Test wine 1, 1
- 2, Test wine 2, 3

### Drinks

- id, name, type_id
- 1, Test drink, 2

### Types

- id, name, type
- 1, Red, App\Wine
- 2, Cocktail, App\Drink
- 3, White, App\Wine

I'm using the framework "Laravel" and I'm aware of polymorphic relations. But is that the right way to go? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

I hope my question makes sense, and that someone has some tips to throw my way :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to follow One To One (Polymorphic) relation for this.

**wines** Model name:- **Wine**

```
id 
name
```

**drinks** Model name:- **Drink**

```
id, 
name,
```

**types**

```
id - integer
body - text
typeable_id - integer
typeable_type - string
```

You're following correct one. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

Comment: But what if I have 2 wines with the same type?

Types

id, name, typeable_id, typeable_type
1, Red, 1, App\Wine
2, Red, 2, App\Wine

Both Wine 1 and 2 should have the same type "Red". But by doing it this way it will make 2 types both named "Red". How can I make them have the same type?

Comment: Okay, the comments remove all formatting. So I hope my last comment makes sense.

Comment: Oh yes, it should be One To One (Polymorphic), so next time if RED comes for Wine it'll update. check this one https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

Comment: I don't understand how it can be a one to one. 1 Wine can only have 1 Type. But 1 Type can belong to multiple Wines. So it should be One to Many, no? But it's like it should be One to Many inverted. But how does inverted work with polymorphism?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the latter.

The DB looks like this:

### Wine

```
id, name, type_id
```

### Drink

```
id, name, type_id
```

### Type

```
id, name, model
```

---

Example:

### Wine

```
1, 2013 Gran Selezione, 1
2, 2013 Barolo Bussia, 1
3, 2018 Juwel Riesling, 4
```

### Drink

```
1, Blueberry Mojito, 2
2, Chili-infused honey, 3
```

### Type

```
1, Red, App\Wine
2, Cocktail, App\Drink
3, Garnish/Mixer, App\Drink
4, White, App\Wine
```

Then in my WineController and DrinkController I'm going to validate the type_id like this:

- Wine:
  'type_id' => 'required|integer|exists:types,id,model,"App\Wine"'
- Drink:
  'type_id' => 'required|integer|exists:types,id,model,"App\Drink"'